# Where does this expression for uncertainty comes from?

Tags: taylor-expansion, error-propagation

With some changes in notations and names, I'm often seeing my (engineering) students using the following technique to estimate uncertainty from measurements:

Suppose that $x_1,...,x_n$ are measured with uncertainties $\delta x_1,...,\delta x_n$, and these measured values are used to compute the function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$. If the uncertainties in $x_1,...,x_n$ are independent and random, then the uncertainty in $f$ is
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\delta f = \sqrt{ \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\delta x_1  \right)^2 + ... + \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\delta x_n  \right)^2 }
\end{equation}

Partial derivatives here are assumed on the point that's the actual measurement of what's being measured, and the $\delta x_i$ are taken accordingly to the uncertainty of the measurement.

I can see an obvious motivation here: using its degree one Taylor polynomial as an approximation to the function $f$ near one point of its domain $(a_1,...,a_n)$ (assuming differentiability):
$$
f(x_1,...,x_n)\simeq \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (x_i-a_i)
$$

Problem is: why using squares for the equation of $\delta f$? If you square the two sides of the first degree Taylor polynomial of $f$, then it would have cross-terms between partial derivatires with respect to different coordinates. Does the uncertainty formula means that these should be considered as zero when it assumes that the variables are "independent and random"? It seems to me that, even when these variables are "independent" (like, radius and height of a cilinder), these cross-terms product's uncertainties can affect the final uncertainty (volume of cilinder) more than the estimative would have us believe.

Working with the inequalities does not lead to the desired result.

Not sure if I was clear. The main reference here is John R. Taylor's "Introduction to Error Analysis", 1997. Check near equation 3.47 pg 75.

Curiously, the author "Taylor" does not mention the "Taylor" polynomial. So many lost opportunities here.

Comment: It is an estimate of the error, $\|f(x+\delta)-f(x)\| \approx \|f'(x) \delta\| = \sqrt{\sum_k (f'(x)_k \delta_k)^2}$, in this case the norm is Euclidean.

Comment: @copper.hat This expression of gave me works when $f$ has only one variable. I'm asking the same question, but when $f$ has more than one variable.

Comment: What do you mean by one variable? Surely $x,\delta \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: If $f$ has more than one variable, in your context, then what do you mean by  $f'$? I'm more used to denote by $f'$ the derivative of a function with only one variable. Do you mean its gradient vector?

Comment: Another view point is that the variance of the expression $f'(x) \delta$ is $\sum_k (f'(x)_k) ^2\operatorname{var} \delta_k$.

Comment: No, I mean the derivative which in this case is the transpose of the gradient vector.

Comment: That's why I didn't get it, it's too much information to simply denote it by $f'$ without any other mention.

Comment: I would write your second expression above as $f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(x) (x-a)$. With a gradient this would be written as $f(x) \approx f(a) +\langle \nabla f(a), x-a \rangle$.

Comment: It is fairly normal in a mathematical context...

Comment: I'm fairly more used to denote the gradient vector as $grad(f)$ or $\nabla f$ instead, and I'm less than a month away from defending my phd thesis... but anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Mine was three decades ago :-). Good luck. Using $\nabla$ for the gradient is standard.

Comment: I'm still curious as why no one mentions this estimative as simply being the norm of the directional derivative (assuming $\delta$ as a direction anyway).

Comment: @copper.hat No harm meant :) It's simply not an usual notation anymore.

Comment: There are two interpretations, one is just a straight error approximation using Taylor and the second is as a variance (see my 3rd comment).

Comment: I assure you the notation is in common use today for the Fréchet derivative. Gradients are meaningless unless one is in an inner prodct space.

Comment: I'm more used to writing it as $Df$ instead of $f'$. Also, my students are mostly engineering undergrads; I'd rather keep consistent with their literature and use gradient vectors.